# storing data from a callback function SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to swift and I've probably formatted everything in quite a strange way, sorry in advance.

I'm trying to store some data I'm retrieving from an api call that's inside another function( getTime). That function has a callback as a parameter that I define when I call getTime. I don't know if what I've written makes any sense at all, but I can't store the value I get from the callback function in a variable to use outside getTime.

This is the function:

```
private func getTime(completionHandler: @escaping (_ Film: String) -> String) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: urlTime)!, completionHandler: {(stats, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
         print("Error with fetching films: \(error)")
         return
        }
           guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                      (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                  print("Error with the response, unexpected status code: \(response)")
                  return
                }
        if let stats = stats,
            let result2 : ResponseStats = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseStats.self, from: stats) {
             completionHandler(result2.response.players[0].steamid ?? "there is no data")
        }
    })
   
    task.resume()                
}
```

And this is how I call it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var smth: String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        getData(from: url)
        
        getTime{
            smth in
            self.smth? = smth
            return smth
        }
        
        print(smth) // this outputs to the console as nil
    }
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `getTime` is a async call, where as you are trying to print smth synchronously in print statement which is the immediate statement after `getTime` basically your print executes even before your closure which sets `self.smth` is even executed. Your statement "but I can't store the value" is incorrect, there is no issue in saving it its just that you are trying to print it even before you save it

Comment: Yes move the print inside the getTime closure. Also by looking at your code it seems you cab change the declaration of the closure to `(String) -> Void`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari thank you for the clarification! then,  how can I access the value from outside the function (not for printing)?

Comment: @markliss: what exactly is your requirement, what you are doing is not wrong, but wherever you access you should be aware data might be there or might not be there because its async call accessing it